# Need help with CodeIgniter v2.0.2

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks

I'm new to CI. Anyone could help to the latest version of CI. most of the Tutorial is for last version and it didn't work for the latest version. please help.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? New to it also, so far...not a big fan.

Comment: currently i'm trying the tutorial at this page http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-basics/# however it will only work for CI v1.7 . but now i am using CI v2. so if anyone could let me know the tutorial for latest version

Comment: I started w/ version 2.0...no tuts to be found... I posted some links for you that should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still get started using what's availabe for 1.7, if you pay attention to how file structure changed between the two versions (ie the System and Application directories are now separate). To that, many of the tuts you'll find are applicable - bearing in mind that the paths may differ, and you'll want to verify that the functions are still supported in 2.0 by use of the [User's Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html)).

If you walked through the tut in your link, using the Models, Views, Controllers directories inside Application, you'd get a "Hello World" page.

The User's Guide is a great tool, as are the [Community Forums](http://codeigniter.com/forums/).

Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

I recently migrated a site using CodeIgniter from 1.7 to 2.0. - I found the following link to be very useful:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/05/upgrading-to-codeigniter-2.0